# 403 forbidden when trying to get or set presence - Graph API - Delegated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. We have this functionality where employees check-in and check out work day from a button.

I want to add this button the functionality to change Microsoft teams status (`setPresence` using Graph API SDK).

Successfully implemented Sign in/Sign out and I'm also well aware I will need to use delegated permissions.

e.g: I can send messages to channels on behalf of users without any problem...

Yet I'm getting an error

> 403 Error: Forbidden

when trying to do:

```
var requestBody = new SetPresencePostRequestBody
                      {
                          SessionId = appId,
                          Availability = "Available",
                          Activity = "Available"
                      };
 
await graphClient.Users[user.Id]
                 .Presence
                 .SetPresence
                 .PostAsync(requestBody);
```

Edit 2: This won't work either.

```
await graphClient.Me.Presence.SetPresence.PostAsync(requestBody2);
```

I tried to add more permissions, checked if I'm aiming to the right `appId` (which I'm sending as `sessionId`)

[Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY8qZ.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, it looks like that the delegated permission `Presence.ReadWrite` has not been granted by the admin.

Anyway, I'm afraid that with the delegated permission `Presence.ReadWrite`, you can set presence only signed-in user.

It will not allow you to set presence of other users. This is possible only with the application permission `Presence.ReadWrite.All`.

Comment: Presence.ReadWrite doesn't need admin permission from what I see, right? Also, I understand your point about not being able to set presence for other users but only for yourself, right? i'm editing my post, it also doesn't let me edit my own presence (for signed in user)

Comment: One possibility is that the user on whose behalf the app is acting does not have the necessary permissions to perform the operation. You may want to check the user's role and permissions to ensure that they have the necessary access. Another possibility is that there could be an issue with the app's authentication or authorization. You may want to check the app's configuration and make sure that it is set up correctly.

Comment: @JuanV Even if you see in Azure Portal that some permission doesn't need admin grant, there can be some tenant policy applied to enforce admin grant but it's not reflected in Azure Portal. So, I would recommend always grant permissions by admin. At least you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this by removing sessionId and also once cross-check the permissions you provided,Wheather you are misssing to grant any premission or not.

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(accessToken);
var requestBody = new SetPresencePostRequestBody
{
    Availability = "Available",
    Activity = "Available"
};
await graphClient.Me.Presence.SetPresence().Request().PostAsync(requestBody);
```

Comment: Compiler Error... PresenceRequestBuilder doesn't not contain Definition for Request()...

Comment: Graph SDK V5 removed the need of Request() - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md